# Hover effect on skewed div without change background

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, skew

I need help to improve my css. I want made a hover effect in a skew div without affect my image put on div.

```css
.overlay-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  transform: skew(-10deg);
  display: inline-block;
}

.overlay-box img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease-in-out .7s background;
  transition: ease-in-out .7s opacity;
}

.content:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

.info {
  font-size: 6vh;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay-box">
  <img src="img/bg1.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="content">
    <a href="#" class="info" title="Full Image">SERVIÇOS</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this code affect my background image, how I can skew my div and my image continue on square aspect.

Comment: you want the text only to be skewed? not the black background right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the inverse skew on the image and adjust overflow:

```css
.overlay-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  transform: skew(-10deg);
  display: inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:20px;
}

.overlay-box img {
  height: 100%;
  width:calc(100% + 40px);
  margin:auto -20px;
  transform: skew(10deg);
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease-in-out .7s background;
  transition: ease-in-out .7s opacity;
}

.content:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

.info {
  font-size: 6vh;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay-box">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/400/" alt="">
  <div class="content">
    <a href="#" class="info" title="Full Image">SERVIÇOS</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello, i tried do this, but on my div overlay-box, it is shown the background. She are not overlay the div.  did you see the effect in run snippet ?

Comment: @AndréAlanAlves i didn't get you ... can you please elaborate more

Comment: hello, i want my image cut of the same shape of the div skewed, but without affect the image. Did you can understand ?

Comment: I think i have need cut the image before i made the effect, i am correct ?

Comment: Hello, currently i have this, but the image has a distortion and i don't want this distortion on my image.  but she has to stay with the cut Did you understand me ? http://andrealanengenharia.com.br/templates/1/newindex.php

Comment: @AndréAlanAlves yes and this is what i did in my update answer :) using the inverse skew you remove the distortion then i added an overflow to keep it inside the cut part

Answer (score 1):

The skew needs to be in the "content" then is the background square and the animation skewed.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        .overlay-box
        {
            position: absolute;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .overlay-box img
        {
            height: 320px;
            width: 380px;
        }

        .content
        {
            position: absolute;
            margin-left: 25px;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: auto;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 50%;
            opacity: 0;
            transform: skew(-10deg);
            transition: background .7s ease-in-out;
            transition: opacity .7s ease-in-out;
        }
        .content:hover
        {
            opacity: 1;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
        }
        .info
        {
            font-size: 6vh;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .content a
        {
            color:white;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="overlay-box">
        <img src="Download.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="content">
            <a href="#" class="info" title="Full Image">SERVIÇOS</a>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to skew the text but not the background image AND not the background color. Here's my solution.

1. [HTML] Place a div inside your `a` tag and place the `class="info"` there.
2. [CSS] Move your `skew` from class `.overlay-box` to `.content:hover .info` selector. Make sure you include the space between.

```css
.overlay-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
                                     /*remove skew*/
  display: inline-block;
}

.overlay-box img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(100,100,100,1);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: ease-in-out .7s background;
  transition: ease-in-out .7s opacity;
}

.content:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

.content:hover .info {               /*add this*/
  transform: skew(-10deg);
}

.info {
  font-size: 6vh;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.content a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay-box">
  <img src="img/bg1.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="content">
    <a href="#" title="Full Image"><div class="info">SERVIÇOS</div></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please consider accepting my answer if it helped you solve your problem. Thanks!